# Sens de « ben là » (en québécois)

Tags: sens, québec, interjections

Si dans diverses circonstances j'ai l'impression qu'en québécois *« ben là »* vaut juste pour un *« euh »* neutre, j'ai l'impression que parfois il porte plus de sens que ça.

Par exemple, que parfois il veut dire *« c'est ça »*. Me trompè-je ? A-t-il d'autres sens encore ? (peut-être parfois porte-t-il un *« je sais pas »* ?).

Et comment fait-on pour savoir, le cas échéant, lequel de ces sens s'applique ?

Comment: ( je suis en train de relire "Magasin Général" :-) )

Answer (score 5):

Je présente ici quelques exemples et relève certaines difficultés que j'annote brièvement selon ma compréhension, afin d'alimenter la réflexion sur cette locution :

> *Rose Ouimet.* — Comment ça, commère comme que chus. T'es pas ben ben
>   gênée ! Tu sauras que chus pas plus commère que toé, Gabrielle Jodoin
>   !
>
> *Gabrielle Jodoin.* — Voyons donc, tu sais ben que tu peux rien garder
>   pour toé !
>
> *Rose Ouimet.* — Ah ! **ben là**, par exemple... Si tu penses...
>
> [[*Les Belles-Soeurs*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Belles-s%C5%93urs), M. Tremblay, ed. *Leméac/Actes Sud*, 1972 (1965) ]

On a une phrase exclamative pour marquer la surprise et l'indignation, le classique ; voir la locution *par [exemple](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/exemple)* (*Tiens! Ah!/Oh! Ça par exemple!* - *TLFi*, D.3. ; où *ça* semble tenir un rôle similaire.). *Ben* est omniprésent dans l’œuvre mais en feuilletant rapidement je n'ai identifié que ce seul passage avec *ben là* comme tel.

---

On peut jeter un coup d’œil à un texte populaire de Claude Meunier/Louis Saïa mis en scène pour la télévision, 20 ans après la pièce de Michel Tremblay :

> (16:28) *Georges*. — Mais tu sais, il faut lui pardonner, une femme ça
>   pense pas toujours à ce que ça dit hein...
>
> *Jeannine*. — Ben, c, c, c'est pas une raison pour qu'elle me parle à travers son chapeau.
>
> *Georges*. — Ben là, **là** tu tiens quelque chose là. [fait un mouvement du doigt vers elle ; il veut dire qu'elle a mis le doigt sur un point important, qu'elle a un bon argument]
>
> [ [*Les Voisins*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Voisins_%28film,_1987%29), C. Meunier/L. Saia, 1987, ma retranscription ]

Meunier réussit à mettre différemment trois fois *là* (sur huit syllabes) dans sa dernière phrase. D'abord l'interjection où l'on marque par sa réaction le propos précédent. Ensuite le deuxième *là*, prononcé bien plus clairement et plus haut ; on insiste plus nettement ou concrètement sur le moment propos ou le fait de son existence (*maintenant*, *dans ce cas*, *ici*). C'est particulièrement appuyé, et on pourrait sans se tromper parler d'exagération dans cette approbation du propos de *Jeannine*. Et donc il va sans dire que c'est exprimé sans aucune connotation négative, puisqu'on ne fait que s'exclamer, spécifier et souligner la trouvaille. On peut sans doute réaliser le même sens avec moins de *là* (*ben, LÀ tu tiens qqc.*) ou transposer autrement (interj. + *tu tiens vraiment qqc. [avec ton dernier propos]*).

> (56:22) *Jeannine*. — Mets-toi donc à côté du sofa... [tsk] me semble
>   que le sofa aurait mieux paru si t'avais mis ta chemise jaune... [elle
>   se place près d'un fauteuil] Tu trouves pas que... tu trouves pas que
>   j'ai l'air folle ?
>
> *Bernard*. — Avec le sofa ?
>
> *Jeannine*. — **Ben non, là**, tout seul, de même ?
>
> *Bernard*. — Me semble que non. [*ding dong*] Ça doit être eux-autres !
>
> *Jeannine*. — Dis-moi-le donc que j'ai l'air folle...
>
> *Bernard*. — Ben oui mais c'est plus le temps là... [il va répondre]
>
> [ [*Les Voisins*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Voisins_%28film,_1987%29), C. Meunier/L. Saia, 1987, ma retranscription ]

Ce n'est pas *ben là*, mais *ben non*, une interjection et une négation (proche de *[mais](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mais) non*), suivies de l'adverbe *là* pour *ainsi/comme ça/en soi* (c-à-d. sans le sofa). Avec le *ben oui* final, il concède que oui il veut bien le lui dire (ce dont elle a l'air), et non pas que oui elle en a l'air (folle), mais c'est tout comme. *Ben* en soi accompagne fréquemment d'autres mots dans des phrases exclamatives où sa fonction ressemble à celle d'une interjection.

---

Dans d'autres réponse on a parlé de l'[*intonation*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16454) et c'est un bon point en plus de celui du contexte/de la [*polysémie*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16453). À mon avis, il faut aussi se soucier du *débit* pour éviter la confusion, et donc de la ponctuation quand on retranscrit. Avec les réactions d'étonnement, d'exhortation où l'on chigne (*ben lààààà !*) etc., ponctuer avec la virgule est inexact selon moi : il s'agit de « ben là ! » et non de « ben, là ! ». On peut s'en convaincre, si ce n'est déjà fait, avec les exemples suivants :

> [Je cherche souvent mes clés alors qu'elles sont devant moi sur la
>   table. Mon interlocuteur est régulièrement témoin de ce cirque. Je dis
>   : ]
>   Q.*— Mais où sont mes clés ?*
>   R.
>   — **Ben là !**
>  [de l'étonnement à l'indignation feinte, pouvant aller jusqu'au sarcasme ; indiquant ici que ça saute aux yeux, que c'est évident ou que selon une norme j'aurais dû savoir]
>  — *Ben là là !*
>  [on en a assez, par ex. de mon comportement, de ma question, c'est sur le point de dépasser les bornes]
>  — *Ben,
>   là (ou là là) !*
>  [là devant moi, ici, ou là où l'on regarde
>   ou pointe du doigt ; ou *là là*, en précisant, en guidant
>   l'interlocuteur vers/à cet endroit]
>  — *Elles sont pourtant ben là !?*
>  [on conteste (avec pourtant) la raison de mon affirmation par le constat
>   qu'elles sont effectivement ici, à l'endroit où elles
>   doivent se trouver ; la ponctuation finale témoigne de la réaction]
>   — *Elles sont pourtant ben, là !?* (x) 
>  [être bien (x), confortable à cet endroit ou maintenant (x) ; un non-sens ici]
>
> ---
>
> [Sans contexte]
>   ***Ben là***, il faut y aller ! [l'étonnement face à l'hésitation imprévue, l'exhortation moralisatrice avec *c'est qu'il faut*]
>  *Ben, là il faut y aller/il faut y aller là !*
>   [davantage *mais, il faut y aller maintenant*]

C'est que la virgule marque une pause. Séparer *là* de *ben* avec la virgule le dégage de l'interjection et semble lui redonner une valeur supérieure comme adverbe. Peu importe l'analyse, le sens diffère si on introduit une pause, et ce n'est donc pas une virgule d'agrément mais bien une modulation du débit qui emporte ici celle du sens à mon avis.

Answer (score 4):

Je ne crois pas que je puisse construire un exemple où la traduction qui me viendrait à l'esprit serait *c'est ça*. Des exemples seraient bienvenus.

*Ben là* s'emploie aussi, entre autres, pour exprimer une certaine incrédulité, parfois combinée à de l'agacement.

Quant à la dernière question... comme pour n'importe quelle expression polysémique: contexte, contexte, contexte!

Answer (score 2):

[This example](https://books.google.com/books?id=yx0DCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA149&dq=%22BEN,%20L%C3%80!%22%20%22alors%20L%C3%80!%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMIgpSRv-vvyAIVxtg-Ch3j7QBw#v=onepage&q=%22alors%20la%2C%20ben%20la%22&f=false) of its usage ...

(from ‘Proceedings of the Fourth International Congress on Mathematical Education’ edited by M. Zweng, Green, Kilpatrick, Pollack, Suydam via Goggle Books)

... has "ben là" right next to “Alors là,” which indicates that “Ben là” at least has a connection with “Alors là” and, by extension, that it could perhaps be used in some, if not all, contexts where/when “Alors là” would be used in France.

(I’m not entirely sure where/when that would be, but see [this link](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/alors-l%C3%A0.836039/) for possibilities, such as when it’s used for “expressing astonishment towards something outstanding made or said by any other person.” (from a ‘Word Reference’ forum thread)

As for possible different uses/meanings for “Ben là” in Québec (and translations of it into English), “[OffQc | Québécois French Guide](http://offqc.com/2010/12/29/meaning-of-ben-la-in-french/)” provides the following examples:

-J’suis pas capable!
-Ben, là! (Oh, come on!)

-J’ai dépensé 300 dollars.
-Ben, là! (What???)

-Va ranger ta chambre tout de suite!
-Ben, làààà! (Nooo! I don’t want to!)

So it seems, as Circeus correctly notes, that context is the best, if not only guide, with maybe a little help from the speaker's intonation and inflection, to determine which sense best applies.

Comment: _Alors là_ is certainly useful sometimes! I think in some cases, _Oh, come on_ won't be adequate, and _Oh, please_ + sarcasm may be required. I disagree with the use of commas in the last three examples, but equating _lààààà_ for _noooo_ re: intonation, is interesting!

Answer (score 2):

'Ben là' n'est équivalent ni à un 'euh' neutre, ni à 'c'est ça', au Québec. Il est équivalent aux exclamation de surprise, d'affirmation ou d'indignation suivantes :

1. Ça alors!
2. Franchement! : 'Ben là, utilise pas la brosse
   de toilette pour laver la vaisselle!'
3. C'est évident : 'Crois-tu que je devrais porter des bobettes pour faire du bunjee?' -Ben là!'
4. C'est injuste : 'Tu sors pas dehors avant d'avoir rangé tes jouets. -Ben là!'
5. Je ne sais pas / J'hésite : 'Est-ce que je peux emprunter ta tondeuse une quatorzième fois cette semaine? -Ben là... tu veux faire quoi avec au juste?'